# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in /var/www/html/projectName

Tags: magento2, admin

I am getting this error when trying to access my magento 2 Admin :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in /var/www/html/Project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
#0 /var/www/html/Project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Use of undefine...', '/var/www/html/P...', 73, Array)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have curl extension installed and enabled?

Comment: yes and i can't find the generated diurectory even ui compiled trhe project and i excute the appropriate permissions n

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly about the package curl or the PHP extension is not installed on the server.

Try installing curl and php5-curl:

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl
```

And restart your web server and PHP worker.